# Is it still possible to get locked levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I still play the game: would like to get all the locked levels before I quit.  I have all the levels except the locked ones, 50+ M credits, and only spend bucks on the 25 buck salvage jobs to Csilla, Endor, or Kashyyyk.  I've done it 8 times so far with no luck yet getting locked levels.

Is it possible to get these locked levels, now that support has ended?

Comment: I've removed the poll request from your question, and focused on the problem you are trying to solve.  Hopefully that helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

When I've seen the salvage jobs to Csilla, Endor, and Kashyyk, I've looked with the little 'magnifying glass tool' to see what the possible salvage rewards are and I haven't seen anything but various characters in a long time, at least several months. So I think either the possible salvage list tool is broken (I do remember it working a while ago, listing other possible rewards) or the other rewards are no longer available.

I never did see information on how likely the 25 bux missions were to get a new level, so it's hard to tell if your 8 attempts are enough to conclude that it isn't going to happen.

Comment: I think the characters you see when you hit the magnifying glass never change.  They're just part of the artwork and don't reflect what the actual salvage could be.  I've been looking every time it scanned since I read your post.  I'll keep checking and update later if they change!

Comment: I recall that they used to change when the salvage operation was just introduced, and that when a level was a possible salvage there was a block-type image listed there.  There also used to be VIPs as possible salvage rewards, and I think you could see those pictured as well.  But now I agree, the artwork is identical and has been for months.  I haven't seen anything but money, Imperial items, or "you already have this reward, have some bux" as salvage rewards in a long time.

Comment: I just got a character from a salvage droid to Kashyyyk at the 25 bux level.  "Freyyr" from Galactic Registry: Series 1.  So maybe if characters are available, the locked levels still are.  So far, I've sent 12 total droids at the 25 bux level to Csilla, Endor, or Kashyyk and all I've gotten are credits, inventory, and one lousy character :)  ....but still trying.  If I don't get a locked level after 100 tries I'll throw in the towel.

Comment: I got a,character after the game was pulled from virtual shelves. This tells me the Galactic Series is in part embedded in the app. Planets might be bigger than the app can manage, and may have always required online connection to add successfully. Still trying though, two years later...